# WinRT StorageFile DisplayName strange behavior

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, storagefile

In a Windows 8 app on Windows 8.1 I use the DisplayName property of StorageFile to get a 'friendly' file name.

In the majority of the cases the result is the name of the file **without** the extension but sometimes the result is the name of the file **with** the extension. This second case seems to happen when I create a new folder and immediately create a file in it.

Does anyone know if there is a consistent rule for this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange but You can create extension method which the result would be frienldy name of this file.

I'd wrote it this way:

```
public static class StorageFileExtensions
{
    public static string ToFrienldyName(this StorageFile file) {
        return file.DisplayName.Replace("." + file.FileType, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would an explanation of the strange behavior. The workaround is easy. Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension for example.

Comment: @sevenmy Oh, I'm sorry in that case, I did not understand the intention of question.