# How to make the StorageFile.DisplayName getter exclude the FileType systematically in UWP

Tags: uwp, storagefile

This question was already asked but did not receive an answer, whereas it will be important to understand how the Storage API in UWP works.

[WinRT StorageFile DisplayName strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118887/winrt-storagefile-displayname-strange-behavior)

I am saving files in different formats (gif and json), so I need to keep track of the common `StorageFile.DisplayName` getter, but the behavior of this property is obscure because sometimes the `FileType` (.gif or .json) is included in the DisplayNme and sometimes it is not.

The reason why of this behavior is the purpose of this question and possibly I am looking at a clear answer on how to have full control on the `DisplayName` where I need to keep the `FileType` outside of the former without resorting to string manipulation.

The only progress I made is to be able to reproduce this "bug"; indeed it seems that the `FileType` is always included when the file created is in AppData's LocalSettings, and not included if for instance the file is stored in the `PictureLibrary`. My code is dead trivial, it uses

```
var fileName = "Test.gif";
var settingsFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("SettingsFolder", folderCreationCollisionOption);
var file = await settingsFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, fileCreationCollisionOption);
```

or

```
var fileName = "Test.gif";
var settingsFolder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("SettingsFolder", folderCreationCollisionOption);
var file = await settingsFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, fileCreationCollisionOption);
```

The former returns for file.DisplayName "Test.gif", and the latter "Test" as desired. However, I need to work in the AppData.

Comment: Try passing the DisplayName (or the full StorageFile.Path) into `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(....)`

Answer (score 0):

The StorageFile.DisplayName return a user-friendly name for the file.
In UWP apps always use as follows:

to get file extension:

```
StorageFile.FileType
```

To get name of file and it's extension:

```
StorageFile.Name
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. You can get "Test.gif" with DisplayName as said above.